# how to get the function(s) under the integral sign in definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Say we have the definite integral:
$$\int_a^b{f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x} = \alpha$$
Given, $a, b,$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, is it possible to get the functions $f(x)$ in general case?

Thank you

Comment: For just one triple $(a,b, \alpha)$? Or do you have this information for arbitrary $a,b$?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*: \ f_n:x\mapsto\begin{cases}n \ (x<\frac{1}{n})\\ 0 \ (x \geq \frac{1}{n})\end{cases}$. Calculate $\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx$. How many different functions are there for this $a, b, \alpha$ combination?

Comment: I think it's clear that the OP is looking for a way to describe the functions that satisfy the given inequality. It's the only way to interpret the question, really, given that he used the term "functions" and not "function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be many functions that have the same definite integral over a given range.  In fact if you take any $f(x$ with 
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = \alpha
$$
and form $$
g(x) = f(x) + \frac{2x}{b+a}-1  
$$
you will find that $$
\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = \alpha
$$

Comment: You probably mean $g$ instead of $f$ in the last equality.